# Is there a multi-supervisor multi-author PhD thesis culture anywhere in the world?

Tags: phd, thesis, advisor, supervision

Current PhD training culture involves supervisor student relationship, atleast at my institute. There is a risk associated with single point failures that might arise as a result of testing a hypothesis that might result in a "failure" during a PhD. The reasons can be from lazy student, inept supervision, optimistic problem. This results in finally rushing to a hodge podge thesis. Due to the current science attaining interdisciplinary nature, are there examples of multi author multi supervisor thesis being undertaken anywhere in the world?

Comment: Don’t think the idea of group work ie 1 strong one carrying 3 others is part of the philosophy...

Comment: Having two advisors is not uncommon

Comment: @GoodDeeds multiple authors is rarer though.

Comment: What do you mean by 'testing a hypothesis that might result in a "failure"'? I think you have a misconception about statistical research.

Comment: If you work at CERN, you probably have many supervisors and almost all of the publications (maybe all) have many authors. Thousands in a few cases.

Comment: You reasoning doesn't follow into your question.

Comment: @Buffy Let me give an account of my personal experience. I performed an immigration project for first two years of PhD...After comprehensive exam, I had taken up optimistic problem that stretched till 4 and half years, but I could not get results. I was responsible for my own optimism. Finally I changed the problem to a derivative work of my senior which I feel is hodge podge work. With this motivation, I asked the OP.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Let me clarify my thought on student-teacher relationship. In the way this current academia stack is acting as a platform where person X is asking question Y and person Z is giving answer P, my thought is what is it that hinders in incorporating similar culture during PhD training?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.